# How to extract the x and y values from yf.download

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, non-linear-regression, yfinance

i have a simnple issue. I want to download Data from yfinance and store it in a Dataframe. That works.
Now how can i additionally extract the X and Y Values, that are stored in that Dataframe?
I mean, just from the fact, that the Data is plottable i conclude, that there are x and y values for every datapoint on the plot.

Here ist the simple code

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stock = 'TSLA'
start = '2020-11-01'

df = yf.download(stock , start=start)
```

What i finally want to achieve ´would be to use the X and Y values to feed them into a polyfit function.
In that way i am trying to do a regression on the pricechart data from a stock, to finally be able to take derivatives and apply some analysis on that function.

Anybody has a good idea?

I appreciate, thanks a lot,
Benjamin

Comment: The columns of your dataframe are: 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'. Which one do you call X or Y? Which one would you like to predict with the other?

Comment: yes these are the Columns, but there is one more: the Date. And when i plot the Data from the Dataframe, then i guess, i do plot the date from the Dates as the X Value and the Closeprice as the Y Values. Now: How can i iterate through the rows and save the Date as the X Value und the Close Price as the Y Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the date and close price like this:

```
X=df.index
Y=df.Close
```

And if you want to plot the Closeprice accordind to the date:

```
df.reset_index().plot(x='Date', y='Close')
```

If you want to use all the data except the close column to predict the Closeprice, you can keep them with:

```
X=df.drop(columns='Close')
```

Comment: okay, thats wonderfull. And how do i store the timestamps as integers, so that i can feed them into a polyfit function?